# How do I create an array of a class that I only have the textual name for?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm currently creating a library that is designed to look at a bunch of strings and create windows with them.  Currently, only a few lines of code and a huge config file will set it off with a lot of windows and stuff.  I have it set up to read some strings and load classes from them, for parameters for methods.  Here's the method that does it:

```
    private Class<?> getClass(String classname){
        switch(classname){//Check for some primitive type references, since they don't work in the below area
            case "int":
                return int.class;
            case "double":
                return double.class;
            case "boolean":
                return boolean.class;
            case "long":
                return long.class;
            case "short":
                return short.class;
        }
        Class<?> value = null;
        try{
            value = Config.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(classname);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            Error.error(ErrorLevel.severe, "Could not find class- "+classname, ex, ErrorCatagory.classFinding);//A custom error handling system
        }
        return value;//Return the class found from the name
    }
```

It works just fine on normal classes.  For instance, if I put java.lang.String into it, it spits the String class back at me.  If I put javax.swing.JTextField, it spits the right class back at me.  However, if I put java.lang.String[] into it, to request an array of Strings, it crashes, as such:

```
    Warning in catagory code- message = Could not find suitable instance for method- Expected JTextComponent but found JTextField!
    Severe error in catagory classFinding
    May 16, 2012 11:02:35 AM ErrorAdapter severeError
    SEVERE: Could not find class- java.lang.String[]
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.String[]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at Config.getClass(Config.java:389)
        at Config.getClasses(Config.java:398)
        at Config.methodCall(Config.java:492)
        at Config.call(Config.java:415)
        at Config.chainCall(Config.java:439)
        at Config.call(Config.java:409)
        at main.action(main.java:122)
        at main$1$5.actionPerformed(main.java:63)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The first line- the one starting with "Warning"- was caused because it liked crashing if I tried using Class.getDeclaredMethod() on JTextField.class to get the getText() method there.  The rest is the crash report.

Is there a way I might be able to fix this and have it work with any class/array depth (So it would work with java.lang.String[], javax.swing.JTextField[][][], and int[][] without hard-coding any of them)?

Also, on a side note, might there be a better way to get the classes for the primitive types based on a string?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

> Class.forName("[Ljava.lang.String;"); for an array of Strings?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)
http://java.dzone.com/news/obtaining-array-class-java-ref

Comment: Not before, but yes now.  It worked...  for the non-array parts.  I tried running the array ones through, and it crashed with this:  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava/lang/String;`  I tried removing the semicolon in the string and it spat the same thing back at me, but this time with no semicolon.  I also tried the brackets, but same thing.

Comment: Worked over here. Java 1.7 build 4

Comment: Once I updated, it worked, too.  It doesn't work with build 3, but yes above.

Answer (score 2):

`[Ljava.lang.String;` is a runtime signature for class `java.lang.String[]`

```
System.out.println(String[].class.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Array names are denoted differently in Java. You can modify your method as follows to process arrays:

```
private Class<?> getClass(String classname){
    switch(classname){//Check for some primitive type references, since they don't work in the below area
        case "int":
            return int.class;
        case "int[]":
            return int[].class;
        case "double":
            return double.class;
        case "double[]":
            return double[].class;
        case "boolean":
            return boolean.class;
        case "boolean[]":
            return boolean[].class;
        case "long":
            return long.class;
        case "long[]":
            return long[].class;
        case "short":
            return short.class;
        case "short[]":
            return short[].class;
        case "char":
            return char.class;
        case "char[]":
            return char[].class;
    }
    Class<?> value = null;
    int arrayLevel = 0;
    while (classname.endsWith("[]")) {
        classname = classname.substring(0, classname.length()-2);
        arrayLevel++;
    }
    while (arrayLevel-- != 0) {
        className = "[L" + className + ";";
    }
    try{
        value = Config.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(classname);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        Error.error(ErrorLevel.severe, "Could not find class- "+classname, ex, ErrorCatagory.classFinding);//A custom error handling system
    }
    return value;//Return the class found from the name
}
```

Comment: Hm...  I don't see anything that would have it return something like the value of `JTextField[].class`, which is what I am looking for (The value returned is fed into `Class.getDeclaredMethod()` as part of the parameter types).  Where might that be?

Comment: @Superinventor If it can find `JTextField`, the code that checks `endsWith("[]")` should be able to modify the class name to match Java's expectations (i.e. prepend `"[L"` and append `";"` to the name of the element class).

Comment: Yes, I saw that part...  The problem is that it then returns just `JTextField.class` when I add the brackets.  What I want is for it to return `JTextField[].class` when I add the brackets, and not when I don't, so that it looks for the right method when the return value is later used in `Class.getDeclaredMethod()` as a one of the parameter types.

Comment: @Superinventor That's very strange - it shouldn't do that. Did you try debugging it to see that the `classname = "[L"+` branch is taken?

Comment: no.  Now that I look at it, I can see that it would, in effect, do what ptay89 mentioned above, just a little more versatile.  It worked.  Now all I need is a `for` loop to make it compatible with stacked arrays (such as `int[][]`).  I can do that myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a library, be nice to your clients and use the Collections classes instead of arrays.

For primitive types, you can always pass the boxed version (`java.lang.Integer` etc.)

Comment: Except that when I do that, it can't find the method...  Sorry, I forgot to mention where the value returned goes.  It goes to `Class.getDeclaredMethod()` as part of the parameter types, so that kind of thing doesn't really work if the method wants an int.  Thanks anyway, though.